# Corefoundation CFArray ownership

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, core-foundation

I found a strange problem while using Core Foundation Array! Here is the code snippet

```
fname = CFStringCreateWithFormat(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, CFSTR("%s%s"), path, ep->d_name);

CFArrayAppendValue(fileNames, fname);
CFRelease(fname); <---- problem here



cnt = CFArrayGetCount(fileNames);
    for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        fname = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(fileNames, i);
        if (fname) {
            ptr = (char *)CFStringGetCStringPtr(fname, CFStringGetFastestEncoding(fname));
```

The code crashes at the last line. Please correct me if I got this wrong. After I created the CFStringRef, I add it to CFArray. As per my understanding the object is now owned by CFArray. Hence I can safely remove the CFStringRef I originally allocated. But when I do CFRelease(fname); the code crashes when I access the array elements in the second part of the code. Can someone explain what is correct way of doing it? If I remove the CFRelease() then everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [CFMutableArray Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFMutableArrayRef/Reference/reference.html) says:

> The value parameter is retained by theArray using the retain callback
>   provided when theArray was created. If value is not of the type
>   expected by the retain callback, the behavior is undefined.

So looks like this is the issue of the fileNames array creation. Probably the third parameter of the CFArrayCreateMutable function. Since CFString is a CFType try to pass kCFTypeArrayCallBacks there.